# Make XServer ignore the mouseclick that woke up monitor from sleep

Tags: x11, mouse, screensaver, dpms

I have a ARM-Box with a touchscreen, running a Debian variant.

Every time I tap the touchscreen, the monitor turns on, but the now visible application receives a mouse click.

Can I tell the XServer to drop the click that reactivated the monitor, or is this expected behavior and cannot be turned off?

Additional Information: The display is also woken up by a PIR-Sensor that executes the following commands (via GPIO and Python):

```
xset dpms force on
xset +dpms
xset dpms 30 30 30
```

Comment: What about swiping over the screen instead of tapping (thus only moving the mouse cursor, not clicking)?

Comment: The visible application supports drag'n'drop, so swiping results in a different unwanted behavior.